# I can not install Wifi Fern?

Tags: installation, wireless, apt, dpkg, svn

I am having problems installing Wifi Fern

```
@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb

Selecting previously unselected package fern-wifi-cracker.
(Reading database ... 187540 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fern-wifi-cracker (from Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fern-wifi-cracker:
 fern-wifi-cracker depends on aircrack-ng; however:
  Package aircrack-ng is not installed.
 fern-wifi-cracker depends on subversion; however:
  Package subversion is not installed.
dpkg: error processing fern-wifi-cracker (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fern-wifi-cracker
@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 2):

#### Install the dependencies

Run in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will fulfil the dependencies missing - `dpkg` isn't capable of doing this. It will also configure (finish) the installation of `Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to update the system. Then:

```
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Then try again. This will install `aircrack-ng` and `subversion` first, then when you run

```
sudo dpkg -i Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb
```

It should work.

**Edit**

***I have changed the code to reflect the comments on this question. Thank you for pointing them out.***

Comment: Actually a full list of dependencies is found here: http://code.google.com/p/fern-wifi-cracker/

Comment: Why are you advising to install *build* dependencies. He's not going to *compile* subversion and aircrack-ng here in the question, but he's installing a prebuilt binary package with regular dependencies.

Comment: The question states that the dependencies `aircrack-ng` and `subversion` are not installed. How else is he going to install them?

Comment: @SimplySimon If you are advising to install dependencies *manually*, then just use `install`, not `build-dep`. And I think installation of dependencies automatically as in my answer is a lot more user friendly.

Comment: OK, when I tried it I found that supervision had dependencies so I used `build-dep` but it works with `install` so I will change my answer to reflect this. Thank you for your help :)